# Texturing a triangle in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm trying to write a 3d editor. The texture is stored in a file `.bmp`. How can I apply a texture to a triangle with a 3d effect? The matching of the triangle vertex with the texture point is used. Use only `System.drawing`.

[image]

Comment: Another homework? I strongly suggest you  to have a look to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Given that System.Drawing understands only a 2D grid, you're going to be doing a whole lot of math to get this right.  You would probably have better luck using a drawing library that understands 3D coordinates.  Examples are Direct3D, OpenGL, Vulkan...  Plus you would then get the benefit of hardware acceleration, which you'll almost assuredly want for editing models of any size.

Comment: Do you really need to use System.Drawing? This would most likely be far easier in wpf. See random article: ["Apply textures to triangles using WPF and C#"](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/apply-textures-to-triangles-using-wpf-and-c/)

Comment: See: [Using the World Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-the-world-transformation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: I learned that u/z and v/z are linear in screen space. From this, We can derive formulas for converting a point on the screen to texture coordinates. But I didn't find these formulas.